# MySQL trigger before update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to add trigger in mysql ...

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON table_1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN SET 
NEW.`order` = (SELECT 1 + COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`order`) FROM `table_1`), 0));
END
```

And I always get error:

```
Error
SQL query: Documentation

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON table_1
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN SET NEW.`order` = ( SELECT 1 + COALESCE( (


SELECT MAX(  `order` ) 
FROM  `table_1` ) , 0 )
);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter. Otherwise the engine thinks the statement is finished at the first `;`. But that would be wrong.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON table_1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  SET NEW.`order` = (SELECT 1 + COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`order`) FROM `table_1`), 0));
END
|
delimiter ;
```