# What is the correct SQL syntax to set a range constraint between a negative and a positive number?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to database design and I'm curious to know how to set a range constraint for a column between a negative and positive number. My best guess was this:

```
CREATE TABLE exampletable (
    range TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT const1 CHECK (range >= -1 AND range <= 1)
);
```

However, this doesn't work in MySQL. What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: There is no "correct syntax" in MySQL. It simply doesn't support check constraints (but it won't tell you)

Comment: So then I would be limited to doing the check on the application side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL check constraints are ignored. You can use a trigger to cancel the insert/update statement that is out of range.

Use this command in your trigger

```
IF `range` < -1 or `range > 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Range is out of range';
END IF
```

Comment: I didn't know there were if statements in MySQL. So how would I fit that in with the remainder of the table syntax? And would that significantly reduce efficiency?

Comment: You can't put that in the table definition. Put it in a trigger statement. A trigger gets executed every time your table is updated or a new record inserted

Comment: Wow, the funny thing is I was taught about check constraints using MySQL and I was never taught about trigger statements but I just read a bit about them on the documentation and they look pretty useful. Thanks.

Comment: One problem many new MySQL user face is the fact that you need to define another delimiter than `;` when you execute a trigger definition. Otherwise the DB thinks your definition ends at the first `;` which would make it incomplete. See this trigger as an example how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20349872/575376